# Iterating through all files in a root folder to search for specific files using os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

I've tried to search previous questions but I couldn't figure out a solution to my problem.

I have a root folder that has many different subfolders and files. Each subfolder also has files within them and possibly even another subfolder within that subfolder.

I want to iterate through all files in this root folder to find all files that are excel files. I was using the os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".xlsx" to confirm that the file is an excel file. Then I will perform data analysis on these files using pandas.

Here is the full code that I am using to do this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

rootFolderPath = r'.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolderPath):
    for filename in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(filename)[1]) == ".xlsx":
            xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
```

I took my code and added a counter to make sure that is finding all excel files, which should be 85, but I am getting a total of 0.

Here is my code with the counter added:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

rootFolderPath = r'.'

counter = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolderPath):
    for filename in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(filename)[1]) == ".xlsx":
            xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
            counter += 1

print(counter)
```

*UPDATE*

I found a way to solve this if anyone is curious:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

rootFolderPath = r'.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolderPath):
    for filename in files:
        if (filename[-5:-1] == ".xls") and (filename[0] != "~"):
            xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(root + "\\" + filename)
```

So, there were three things that I needed to do:

1. Some of the excel files had extensions of either 'xlsx' or 'xlsm' so I needed a way to account for this.
2. The program was duplicating some of the excel files but adding a '~' at the start of the name, so I had to filter these out as well.
3. The program was not creating a pandas dataframe for the excel files in the root folder itself, so I needed to account for this as well.

Comment: Remove the `os.path.isfile`.  What `splitext` is returning is not a file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `os.walk()`, use `glob.glob()`. It has an option to search recursively through subdirectories.

```
from glob import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(rootFolderPath, "**", "*.xlsx"), recursive=True):
    xlsx = pd.excelFile(filename)
    counter += 1
```